# Maximizing $Q(x,y) = \exp (0.5077 - 0.324 \ln(x))x \cdot y$

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I have been trying to solve the following function:

$$Q(x,y) = \exp (0.5077 - 0.324 \ln(x))x \cdot y$$

My interest is to find the value of $ x $ which maximizes this function. Therefore I proceed by taking $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = 0$ but can’t go beyond this point as I get

$$\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \dfrac{1.12315 y}{x^{0.324}} = 0 $$

I am wondering if a numerical solution instead exists for this problem.

*Clarification:

For simplicity assume $ Q(x,y) = \exp(a + b \ln x) x \cdot y $ where $a = 0.5077$ and $b = -0.324$ as clarified by caverac below. Then I want to take $ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = 0$ and get the value of $x$ which maximises $Q(x,y)$.

Comment: Looks like you have issues with the posed problem - you show a $f(x, y)$, but then show variables like $z$. Is something misstated?

Comment: If the derivative is always positive, then $Q$ gets larger as $x$ gets larger.

Comment: Your definition of $Q$ is ambiguous.  Can't you ignore the .5077 term (as it is an overall irrelevant constant)?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. What I have in mind is $ f(x,y) = \exp(a + b \ln x) x \cdot y $ where $a = 0.5077$ and $b = -0.324$ as clarified by caverac. Then I want to take $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity call $a = 0.5077$ and $b = -0.324$, so that you can write your problem as

$$
Q(x,y) = \exp(a + b\ln x) xy = e^a e^{b\ln x} xy = e^a x^bxy = e^a x^{1 + b}y
$$

So the problem is reduced to finding the optimum value of

$$
f(x,y) = x^{1 + b}y = x^{0.676}y
$$

$(0, 0)$ is a saddle point, that means it is not a bound problem

Comment: The problem is unbounded if $y>0$ though.

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are right in your first observation that if the derivative is always positive, then $Q$ gets larger as $x$ gets larger. This is actually what I would expect since this is a revenue maximization problem in which $Q$ is the total revenue which depends on price ($x$) and quantity ($y$) with the price elasticity of demand taken as inelastic (i.e. quantity demanded respond less than proportionately to a change in price). And yes $y>0$ in our problem and has to be that way since its quantity.